# List menu -- How to execute statement when item is selected?

Tags: php, html, listbox

In Dreamweaver I have a list box or menu/list. 
I am dynamically adding data from an array into it, so when the page loads, I have a list-box with names in.

This is how it looks

```
<?php
       echo "<select name="."username"."id="."username".">";
        foreach ($user_array as $arr) {
        echo "<option>$arr</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
      ?>
```

Now how do I go about making the listbox executesomething when the user selects something in it?

Because I have three other textboxes, and when the user selects a name in the list box, I want to put that name he selected into a variable (also don't know how I'm going to do that with a list box) and then search through my database and insert some of the data of that person in the textboxes.

So all i need to know is:

1. How to create that on event click event and
2. How to put that selected value then in a variable (inside the event)

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want to execute? A software on the computer, run a bit of javascript, run a server side process from PHP? What is the structure of the database, how will you know what to run when? All we see is $user_array and you print out $arr... so it doesn't really help us...

Comment: Hey there. The things i want to execute isnt a problem, i can do that. The only thing i want to know is how that action(selection) event looks, 
like for instance
Onmouseclick
(
)
Thats all, the stuff in the bracket i can do.
because, you see im still struggling with the whole interface of php/html.. Its not as simple as plain C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily execute a javascript function by using something like this:

```
<select name=".$username."id=".$username." onchange='yourfunction()' >
```

Comment: Well, this covers 1/10th of what OP needs to do :)

Comment: I think this question was edited and added to after I posted....  1/10 is better than nothing...

Comment: No, the question was the same. Last edit is 2 mins before your answer, done by me, and I just did formatting (you can see the edit history). If you read carefully, he says he wants to query a database and fill textboxes with the returned data. Your answer is just a tiny start, but yeah, could well put OP on the right track

Comment: Nowwww i see how functions work here!! Thank you!!! 
Ive used this example to make me catch on to what you told me. Thank you!!!!!

`<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert()
{
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="show_alert()" value="Show alert box" />

</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

The following php code generated a select field with a dynamic number of options.

```
<?php
$user_array = Array("Smith", "John", "Bob", "Jake");
echo "<select name="."username"." id="."username".">";
    foreach ($user_array as $arr) {
        echo "<option>$arr</option>";
    }
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The following JavaScript handles change events on the select element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var username = $('#username');
    var selectedValue = null;
    username.change(function(){
       alert(username.val()); 
       selectedValue = username.val();
    });
});
```

Comment: this looks like its gona work... Thank you! Im gona try it now. Ill get back to you on how it went and what happened

Comment: Thank you, i saw with your answer that there were two parts to an event, and used the bottom one, to add the onclick event to my listbox.
Thank you soo much, you really helped me.